# Jquery to remove html elements

Tags: jquery

using jquery I have sucessfully removed a div tag with id using $('#banner').remove();

This actually displays the page without the banner. Is there a way to remove a div tag with an id in the html template as well using Jquery?. I have to do this in HTML page.

When I run the script it has to empty anything in div tag in html template itself.

Thx

Comment: Unclear, what you mean. `$('#any-element-you-like-or-even-the-whole-body').remove();` or `hide()` or `empty()`. You should read about jQuery selectors...

Comment: Ok. I have this html template with a <div id="banner><img ></img></div>. I want to remove this div element from an HTML template. There shoud not be a div element in that page.html after I run this script. Hope that's clear

Comment: See taxicala's answer

Comment: Are you wanting to remove the HTML from the template file and have that changed saved for good? Asked another way, should this change, when run once, be persistent across additional page views?...

Comment: yes. Exactly. Though it's not visible in the browser, I see it in the template(html file). I don't want that. i want it gone. Is there way?.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really unclear, but it seems you want to remove everything inside a specific div, if that's the case:

Use jquery `empty` method:

```
$('#divToEmpty').empty();
```

Or `html`:

```
$('#divToEmpty').html("");
```

Comment: Add the 'remove()' method too and everything is answerd